# run R script from .bat (batch file)

Tags: r, batch-file

I am trying to run a r script using batch file. Currently I am using 
`start"" "shortcut of R"` to open R. However, I wanna R automatically run a r script that I have saved on the computer.

Possibly R will be closed after running the script and user do not see R running.

Is that possible? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19):

[Rscript](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html) is a non-interactive variant of the standard R command, just designed for this kind of use.

For example, under windows you can define a `launcher.bat` like this :

```
PATH PATH_TO_R/R-version/bin;%path%
cd PATH_TO_R_SCRIPT
Rscript myscript.R arg1 arg2
```

In myscript.R  you add the code to read the arguments:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
arg1 <- as.character(args[1])  
arg2 <- as.numeric(args[2])
```

Comment: what happens with arg1 and arg2? lets say I want to `print(arg1)`, what is the code inside myscript.R?