# How to run a R script from the task scheduler via a .bat file

Tags: windows, r, batch-file

I'm a novice when it comes anything outside of coding for R. I've looked up many similar posts but they aren't detailed enough as I'm unfamiliar with many of the terms.

I have a simple R script that's saved on the C: drive. I want it to run from a .bat file for now, which I will later use in the task scheduler to run automatically everyday once it's working.

I saw many posts pointed to this [link](http://turing.une.edu.au/~stat356/Rbatch.html).

The link mentions the working directory but then never mentions anything it again. How does windows command know the folder of the .R script if it's never seems to be entered? Right now I've changed the working directory:

```
cd C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64
```

I don't know where to go from there.

Edit: I'm running windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux:

```
R CMD BATCH [options] my_script.R [outfile]
```

On Microsoft Windows (adjust the path to R.exe as needed):

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH 
   --vanilla --slave "c:\my projects\my_script.R"
```

From [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/batch.html).

Comment: This works, thanks! I had read that CMD BATCH wasn't being used in favor of Rscript.exe as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506007/running-r-code-from-command-line-windows

Comment: So this works in the command line, how would I transfer to a .bat file? I know how to create a .bat file, just don't know what to put in it.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811871/run-r-script-from-bat-batch-file

Comment: In order to run Rscript you need your scrip to be not interactive, take a look at this to get an idea: http://www.statmethods.net/interface/io.html

Comment: Does anyone know how to run CMD BATCH to call a project using `renv?`  I've seen this done using RScript.exe, but not with CMD BATCH.