# Daily R Process

Tags: r, automation

It's likely this question has been asked / answered but I couldn't find the proper post. Likely I'm using the wrong keywords.

I have an SQL system on an Windows machine which runs daily stored procedures for updating models and other maintenance tasks. Currently, I'm looking to do some analysis which is a little bit more involved and I've written a function in R which reads from the Server operates some magic and then loads the new data back into the server.

Is there a standard way of automating this process to run once a day? Hoping to keep my system as autonomous as possible.

Comment: In UNIX-alikes, this would probably be a chron job.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not on a UNIX-alike machine. Original post edited to reflect this.

Comment: On Windows you can create a `.bat` file to execute your script using `Rscript` or `R CMD BATCH` and use the windows task scheduler to automate the execution. There are a few similar questions on SO; [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933597/how-to-run-a-r-script-from-the-task-scheduler-via-a-bat-file).

Comment: You should add the appropriate tag. And please do search. When I searched on "windows scheduling" I got 11,000+ hits.

Comment: @BondedDust thanks for the hints. I tried some googling but obviously my choice of keyword was subpar.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933597/how-to-run-a-r-script-from-the-task-scheduler-via-a-bat-file) should help get you started.