# Unable to run R script through .bat files in Windows Server

Tags: r, batch-file

I'm trying to run a R script through a .bat file. When I run myself the commands line by line it works. But when I try to run the .bat file, it doesn't works.

This is the .bat file

```
cd "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin"
R CMD BATCH "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\testa_vps.R"
```

This is the R script

```
setwd('C:\Users\Administrator\Documents')
file.create('mycsv.csv')
```

Comment: You might consider `Rscript` (`Rscript.exe`) rather than `R CMD BATCH`, as discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811871/run-r-script-from-bat-batch-file) - I've found the former to be easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks! But I tried with Rscript also, and it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert with Windows and generally try to stick to Unix-like systems for things like this, but I have found that using programs non-interactively (e.g. via `.bat` files) is usually less error-prone when you add the appropriate directories to your (user) `PATH` variable, rather than `cd`ing into the directory and calling the executable from within the `.bat` file. For example, among other things, my user `PATH` variable contains `C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-3.0\bin\;` - the directory that contains both `R.exe` and `Rscript.exe` - (where `PROGRA~1` is an alias for `Program Files` which you can use in an unquoted file path, since there are no spaces in the name).

After you do this, you can check that your `PATH` modification was successful by typing `Rscript` in a new Command Prompt - it should print out usage information for `Rscript` rather than the typical `xxx is not recognized as an internal or external command...` error message.

In the directory `C:\Users\russe_000\Desktop\Tempfiles`, I created `test_r_script.r`, which contains

```
library(methods)
setwd("C:\Users\russe_000\Desktop\Tempfiles")
file.create("mycsv.csv")
```

and `test_r.bat`, which contains

```
Rscript --vanilla --no-save "C:\Users\russe_000\Desktop\Tempfiles\test_r_script.r"
```

Clicking on the Windows Batch File `test_r` ran the process successfully and produced `mycsv.csv` in the correct folder.

---

Before running `test_r.bat`: 
[image]

---

After running `test_r.bat`: 
[image]

---

I've never worked with a Windows server, but I don't see why the process would be fundamentally different than on a personal computer; you just may need your sysadmin to modify the `PATH` variable if you don't have sufficient privileges to alter environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, the path tip worked. But I'm still having the same problems. When I run the .bat file, it doesn't work even running it as administrator

Comment: Hmm that's strange. When you tried to run the `.bat` file did it generate any error messages? And how did you run it - from Command Prompt or by double clicking on it?

Comment: I tried with double click. Now I tried by the command prompt, and it returned that Rscript is not a recognized command. But I can run Rscript commands outside the .bat file. How can I define the Rscript inside the . bat file?

Comment: Hi, I've changed the path and my `.bat` is working when running from my computer but not from others. Do you know why can be that?

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by @nrussel in the comments you should use `RScript.exe` for this.

Create a file `launcher.bat` with the following content:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Documents
Rscript testa_vps.R
```

In addition, add `C:\Program Files\R\R-[your R version]\bin\x64;` or `C:\Program Files\R\R-[your R version]\bin\i386`to the System PATH variable in the `Environment Variables` menu depending if you run `R` on a 64-bit or 32-bit system.

I just tested the approach above successfully on a Windows Server 2008 64-bit system and `mycsv.csv` got created as expected.

**EDIT**

One important point I forgot to mention is the following: You need to specify the path in your R file in the `setwd()` call using `\\` instead of `\`.

```
setwd('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents')
```

Here is a screenshot of the successful run on the Windows 2008 server:

[image]

*Note: I added `cmd /k` to the .bat file so that the cmd window stays open after clicking on the file.*

Comment: Thanks, but when I run Rscript I get Error in unexpected input in " Execution halted

Comment: I edited my answer. Please have a look because I believe the approach above would be the most convenient for you.