# automate tasks in R for Windows 8 platform

Tags: r, automation, task, scheduler, schedule

I would like to have my R script files automatically executed at certain times each day. I have tried to add the script file to the Windows task scheduler but all that does is open up Rstudio and the file but no execution.I followed these steps [Scheduling R Tasks via Windows Task Scheduler](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/scheduling-r-tasks-via-windows-task-scheduler/) but this does not work on my computer. When I create the batch file, command won't open it. I need help!

Comment: The answer I gave [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263741/unable-to-run-r-script-through-bat-files-in-windows-server/28264171#28264171) was tested on Windows 8 - you would just need to add the batch file to the task scheduler after following the steps outlined.

Comment: Conmsider using `jenkins`, a very usefull solution to manage automated tasks. https://jenkins-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

Schedule R scripts/processes with the Windows task scheduler. This allows R users working on Windows to automate R processes on specific timepoints from R itself.

- https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR

If you are looking for a Linux/Unix scheduler, you might be interested in the R package cronR available

- https://github.com/bnosac/cronR