# Can I open a file to make R run the code within?

Tags: r

I am working with R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Gui on Windows. I would like to open a file (perhaps a .txt file, perhaps a .R file, any file of the kind), that launches R and runs the code written in that file.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

My goal is to have a method for my co-workers where they can double-click a file and see the results of my script after running in R. Right now they are copying all my code from a .txt file and pasting it into R.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you want a `.bat` file, see *e.g.* the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811871/run-r-script-from-bat-batch-file

Comment: `source("your file path")` would be a little better than copy&paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using a batch file is to do it entirely in a Windows shortcut.
For instance, on my Windows system:

1. Create a shortcut to `c:/path/to/bin/Rscript.exe`.

   For me, Windows had a "wizard" help me do this, which forced me to just identify the executable. From here, either <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the link or right-click and select Properties, then continue:
2. Change "Start in" to the appropriate directory. If you are relying on specific paths for dependencies, then make sure you set this (and/or use `setwd(...)` within your R script).
3. Add the filename to the command line in "Target", perhaps something like `C:\R\R-3.3.3\bin\Rscript.exe myscript.R`. In this example, `myscript.R` must exist in the directory in "Start in", though there's nothing stopping you from hard-coding the full path.

Using [the link in @neilfws's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811871/run-r-script-from-bat-batch-file) or information here ([How can I read command line parameters from an R script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script), both Marek's and Dirk's answers), you can easily make it react to run-time arguments. For example, if your script includes:

```
opts <- commandArgs()
```

then `opts` will be a `character` vector with

```
c("C:\\R\\R-3.3.3\\bin\\x64\\Rterm.exe", "--slave", "--no-restore", "--file=myscript.R", "--args", "C:\\path\\to\\dragged_file")
```

and your script can "react" to the file (or directory) dragged onto the icon.

One issue with all of this is that it is entirely non-interactive. If you need popups, graphics, or other "discourse" with the user, you'll need something a little different.

Comment: Thank you! Setting the default program that opens the .txt file to the Rscript.exe worked very well.