# How to use a Windows batch file to run an R script, followed by a Python script, then a T-SQL query?

Tags: python, r

I have three separate daily processes that all take a long time to run, which means a lot of waiting around. For some very good reasons, they need to use the different languages.

I'm guessing there has to be a way to run all three, (consecutively as they rely on the previous process being completed,) using a Windows batch file.

Comment: See this question for R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811871/run-r-script-from-bat-batch-file

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e That sounds like it will fit the bill, assuming that the batch commands will wait until the Rscript has completed.
I think the SQL is fairly straightforward, so that only leaves the python.